# Cache folder not writable Bitbucket Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bitbucket, yarnpkg

I have currently a problem to build and to run my app using bitbucket pipeline:

I have a error about the cache folder which is not writable:

```
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/home/node/.cache/yarn" because it is not writable.
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/tmp/.yarn-cache-1000" because it is not writable.
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/tmp/.yarn-cache" because it is not writable.
error Yarn hasn't been able to find a cache folder it can use. Please use the explicit -- 
cache-folder option to tell it what location to use, or make one of the preferred locations 
writable.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I'm using a bitbucket-pipelines.yml and a dockerfile.

Thank you

Comment: You find an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem (also using Docker and Bitbucket Pipelines). Except that I was using k8s to deploy the app.

What I did was change the next line in my deployment to `false`:

```
securityContext:
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false (it was `true`)
```

It solved it for me!

Comment: The question is for Docker, you should provide feedback to solve the issue on Docker not k8s.